# Wrong item count at recyclerview inside a custom adapter of another recyclerview

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, adapter

So I had these two arraylists:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList();

a.add("bear","lion","bird","goose","cat");
b.add("car","bike");
```

Then I add them both to a new arraylist:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList();

list.add(a);
list.add(b);
```

And then, I set this arraylist to a custom adapter for a recyclerview. Inside this adapter, I also set those two arraylists (which is inside the last arraylist) to a recyclerview which is the item view of the adapter. So it is a recyclerview inside a custom adapter of another recyclerview.

However, when I debug the app, the first arraylist which is containing 5 items shows only 2 at the recyclerview. Like the second arraylist. And then, when I deleted the second arraylist and debug the app again, the first arraylist will show its true value.

And if I call notifyDataSetChanged() after the recyclerview show that wrong value, It will show its true value. So, I thought it because certain view (I don't if it's the recyclerview, fragment, or something else) didn't loaded properly yet.

How do I should solve this problem? Thank you.

**EDIT:** 
This is my adapter code:

```
 public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterNearMe.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<List<String>> list;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         public RecyclerView rView;

         public MyViewHolder(View view) {
              super(view);
              rView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rview);
         }
     }

     public MyAdapter (Context context, List<List<String>> list) {
         this.context= context;
         this.list = list;
     }

     @Override
     public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_near_me, parent, false);

         return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
     }

     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final List<String> newList= list.get(position);

        holder.rView.setAdapter(new AdapterRView(context,newList));
        holder.rView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context,3));
     }

     @Override
     public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
     }
}
```

Comment: You should post your adapter code

Comment: Okay, Already posted.

Comment: I think @Raghunandan meant to post whole adapter code :) at least implemented methods.

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView's` `bindViewHolder` gives you functionality to set properties on your cell `view` rather than setting `adapter` for parent `RecylerView`.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

// This should single Model rather than List
final List<Model> newList= list.get(position);

// Instead of creating another recyclerview, check how to create section view
holder.rView.setAdapter(new AdapterRView(context,newList));
holder.rView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context,3));
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand yet how to create a section view, Can you show me a simple example? or maybe a link so I can refer to it. :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the list is a list that I am going to put to the recyclerview inside the adapter, so it cannot be a model or string.

Answer (score 0):

how about setting the adapter for recyclerview in onCreateViewHolder() method (with empty arraylist) ? then populate it with real data, and then call notifyDataSetChange() in onBindViewHolder() ?

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterNearMe.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<List<String>> list;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     public RecyclerView rView;

     public MyViewHolder(View view) {
          super(view);
          rView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rview);
          rView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context,3));
     }
 }

 public MyAdapter (Context context, List<List<String>> list) {
     this.context= context;
     this.list = list;
 }

 @Override
 public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.item_near_me, parent, false);

     MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);
     holder.rView.setAdapter(new AdapterRView(context, new ArrayList<String>));

     return holder;

 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final List<String> newList = list.get(position);

    AdapterRView adapter = holder.rView.getAdapter();
    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.swapList(newList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
 }

 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
 }
}
```

You need to add one additional method to swapping the list of the AdapterRView.class :

```
public class AdapterRView.class {

....

private List<String> list;

    public void swapList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```